# i just wanted to run my Angular project but i found thi problem

Tags: angular

error TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/hp/angular/first/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your tsconfig.json, on the root folder of your angular project. Check that you have :

```
{
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, <-
...
}
```

Comment: thank you it works well


{
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
...
}